# Can we use network neural for nonumeric data?

Tags: neural-networks, predictive-models

I am going to use network net package to do predidction. Tell me please:
Is it neccessary to do scaling of data ?
Is it neccessary to convert all data into numeric/int type ?

I am newbie at this subject, hence these questions can be trivial for you, but not for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the penalized version of neural networks, there is a weight on the scale of the coefficients (check the *decay* parameter in `nnet` in R). So it is necessary to put the coefficients on the same scale rescaling them.

Factor variables are handled in the usual way converting them to dummy variables. Again, if you are worrying about implementation, `nnet` will do it for you.

Comment: hmm, so I can convert data into non-numeric (in my case it is easy). How to set formula and decay parameter, and size parameter in nnet ?) I would like to do prediction

Comment: `nnet(y ~ x1 + x2 + .., decay = 0.01)`

Comment: If `x1 + x2` say that it should use these features to predict of `y` ?

Comment: Yes. If you want to refer to all the variables just type `(y ~ .)`

Comment: So, (1) Should I convert my data (factors) to numeric ? (2) Should I scale convert data ?  I don't know if nnet do it automatically

Comment: 1) No 2) Yes you should

Comment: So tell me: how to scale not-numeric data ? What does mean decay exactly ?

Comment: 1) Use the `scale` function
2) If you look at the ridge regression, it has exactly the same meaning, a penalty based on the square of every coefficient